# Run only when user is logged on

Tags: powershell, scripting, scheduled-tasks

I'm creating a PowerShell script which maps a network drive and I want it to be run at every logon. The commands inside the script work (when I run the commands, it maps the network drive), but the scheduled task doesn't works. By saying "it doesn't work" is that the task doesn't launch at all.

This is my script:

```
$trigger = New-JobTrigger -AtLogOn
Register-ScheduledJob -Name "MountAxiSante20015" -Trigger $trigger -ScriptBlock {
    New-PSDrive -Name "S" -Root "\\SERVEUR\Axisante2000" -Persist -PSProvider FileSystem
}
```

In the task scheduler, I can see the task. In the GUI, in the general tab, the radio button selected is "Run whether user is logged on or not" and that's the problem. I want the task launch only when user is logged on! If I select the radio button "Run only when user is logged on", the task works and is launched at the logon.

So is there a possibility to check this radio button *"Run only when user is logged on"* with PowerShell when creating the task? I have already checked in other threads but I can't find a solution.

Comment: Why use scheduled task? Mapping network drives can be done via group policies and logon scripts.

Comment: Yes, you're right! I don't know why I want to use the Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the specific user according to the [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/PSScheduledJob/New-JobTrigger?view=powershell-5.1)

```
$trigger = New-JobTrigger -AtLogOn -User <domain>\<login>
```

The whole script would then look like this:

```
$trigger = New-JobTrigger -AtLogOn -User <domain>\<login>
Register-ScheduledJob -Name "MountAxiSante20015" -Trigger $trigger -ScriptBlock {
    New-PSDrive -Name "S" -Root "\\SERVEUR\Axisante2000" -Persist -PSProvider FileSystem
}
```

Comment: Even with this parameter the task is not launched... I will check for others ways to do this!